# Run init rc script after package manager have loaded

Tags: services, init.d

I'm writing an init service which make sure a package is installed and if not, it will install the apk.

The problem is, that currently I'm using a boot trigger with `on boot` but when I run pm install from there it doesn't seem to work. I've used a sleep command to wait for the package manager service to load but I would like to find a proper solution.

I've had three ideas which all seems to lead to me to a dead end:

1. wait for a prop to show up, but the package manager service doesn't create any.
2. wait for a file to show up, again no such file exist
3. set my service in a class but it seems to be relevant for the service itself and not the trigger or am I misunderstanding something?

My current service definition is like so:

```
on boot
    exec_background -- /vendor/bin/install.sh
```

Comment: Please share how you are starting the service (e.g. `class_start`, `exec`, ...) and the service definition. What property have you tried to trigger on `sys.boot_completed` or `dev.bootcomplete`?

Comment: You need to wait for the zygote (along with all of its services, which include PackageManager) to start. `on boot` is fired at very early stage. Use `on property:ro.runtime.firstboot=* && property:init.svc.zygote=running && property:init.svc.bootanim=stopped && property:sys.boot_completed=1`.

Comment: Sadly it didn't seem to work, `pm install` still failed

Comment: @yotamN failed with what error? Are the above properties set on your device?